# Converting XmlNodeList to List<string>

Tags: c#, xml, string

Is it possible to convert an `XmlNodeList` to a `List<string>` without declaring a new `List<string>`?

I am looking for a simple implementation for this:

```
System.Xml.XmlNodeList membersIdList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//SqlCheckBoxList/value");
List<string> memberNames = new List<string>();
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode item in membersIdList)
{
    memberNames.Add(library.GetMemberName(int.Parse(item.InnerText)));
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using LINQ:

```
var memberNames = membersIdList.Cast<XmlNode>()
                               .Select(node => node.InnerText)
                               .Select(value => int.Parse(value))
                               .Select(id => library.GetMemberName(id))
                               .ToList();
```

`Cast<XmlNode>()` call is necessary, because `XmlNodeList` does not implement generic `IEnumerable<T>`, so you have to explicitly convert it to generic collection from non-generic `IEnumerable`.

And yes, you can merge all `Select` calls into one if you want:

```
var memberNames = membersIdList.Cast<XmlNode>()
                               .Select(x => library.GetMemberName(int.Parse(x.InnerText)))
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: What's `library` in this context?

Comment: but what is library?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `LINQ to XML` ?

```
List<string> memberNames = XDocument.Load("path")
                           .XPathSelectElements("//SqlCheckBoxList/value")
                           .Select(x => library.GetMemberName((int)x))
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: What's `library` in this context?

Comment: Yep library doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
           XmlNodeList membersIdList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Id");
           var memberNames = membersIdList.Cast<XmlNode>()
                           .Select(x => int.Parse(x.InnerText))
                           .ToList();
```