# How can I filter a list to exclude elements where the InnerText property does not contain "See {"

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using this code to get data from an XML string:

```
XmlNodeList el = doc.GetElementsByTagName("WordDefinition");
```

How can I filter this list using to make another list that excludes those elements where

`el[??].InnerText` does not start with some spaces followed by:

> "See {"

Note I would be happy to filter it by whatever means is possible.  I did try to do some LINQ type of query using a .Where but it seems like XmlNodeList does not allow me to use a .Where.

Comment: Look at the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871908/converting-xmlnodelist-to-liststring) SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OfType()` or `Cast()` before `Where()` :

```
.....
XmlNodeList el = doc.GetElementsByTagName("WordDefinition");
var result = el.OfType<XmlNode>().Where(o => o.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("See {"));
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UOEGZW)</kbd>**

Comment: What is the best way to modify this code to reverse the result.   I use ".Contains" to find results that contain a value, but I want it to display items that don't contain a particular keyword.

Comment: @Auguste Reverse the filter using `!` ? something like  : `...Where(o => !o.SomeProperty.Contains("some keyword"));`

Comment: It works perfectly.  I was putting the "!" sign on a wrong place.  Thanks again.